# HTML-CSS div is 3px taller than child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project that uses several divs of the same class, each containing a single child element that might be an image or an iframe, of unspecified height. I'd like the container div to be exactly the height of its child element, but the default height is 3px taller than the child.

I've got a JSfiddle demonstrating the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/52me041n/2/.

HTML:

```
<div class="outside">
    <img class="inside" id="pic" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.cisco.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fclouds.png&f=1" height="200px"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="outside">
    <iframe class="inside" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VwTnyRHEZSQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outside{
background-color: red;
}
```

I'd like to know whether it's possible to set the div to the proper height with just CSS, and if not, how to right it with JS.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by this? ". I'd like the container div to be exactly the height of its child element, but the default height is 3px taller than the child."

Comment: Say an image is 100px tall, the container div is by default 103px.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/52me041n/3/

Use  -

```
img, iframe {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Was it that easy? I'm wondering why inline display does that now.

Comment: by default an image and iframe gets displayed as INLINE and adds some gap towards bottom. To avoid this, we display as block :) simple

Comment: @user1576628 all inline element including inline-block element has line-height, because they're treated like a text.

Unless you have a block element, or force it to display as block the line-height well be ignored.

Comment: @user1576628 inline elements have space below them to leave space for [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender).

Answer (score 3):

Images are not on the same baseline as text.

add

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

to your img css

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/52me041n/7/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the display property to block for children inside the parent div. As a practice, I always also set margins and pads to 0 too. fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52me041n/6/)

```
.outside > * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For "I'd like to know whether it's possible to set the div to the proper height with just CSS, and if not, how to right it with JS."  <== Yes,

```
<div id="cntr">  </div>
```

css :

```
#cntr { width : 100px; height : 100px; overflow : hidden; }  /* overflow may have other values also like  hidden, auto, scroll
```

*/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52me041n/9/)

```
.outside 
{
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
.outside img, iframe {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hey there's a typo. Its `display` and not `dispaly`.